# jQuery dropdown menu with special animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to build a dropdown menu with jQuery like the following website did:
https://www.eataly.com/

Currently I am hanging on the dropdown animation. I have no idea how they do it and can't figure out how in their code.

My best idea was to slideDown every li element inside the ul of a main menu item. But that doesn't looks like that on the website.

I've uploaded the project here, on jsfiddle it doesn't works well as it in stand-alone site does.
https://github.com/tyurderi/jquery-menu

I'm glad if you can help me building this animation for my menu.

Comment: I've tried to rework the animation like this one (of the menu) on eataly.com. You can see it on https://github.com/tyurderi/jquery-menu/blob/master/js/index.js#L12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "dropdown animation" on the main menu of the site you linked is achieved by CSS transformations, not jQuery.

Look at the code bit in `media-queries.css` file, starting from line 480:

```
/* menu desktop hover effects */
.js-opened-effect .nav-primary > li > ul{
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);       
    transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -moz-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    -o-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;      
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.26s ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.26s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.26s ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.26s ease;
    transition: transform 0.26s ease;
}

.js-opened-effect .nav-primary > li:hover > ul{
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1);       
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
.js-opened-effect .nav-primary ul li > ul{
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    -o-transform: scaleX(0);       
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
    -moz-transform-origin: left;
    -ms-transform-origin: left;
    -o-transform-origin: left;
    transform-origin: left;     
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.26s ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.26s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.26s ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.26s ease;
    transition: transform 0.26s ease;
}

.js-opened-effect .nav-primary ul li.js-sub-opened:hover > ul,
.js-opened-effect .nav-primary > li.js-main-opened ul li.js-sub-opened:hover > ul{
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(1);       
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

That's where you have to look if you want to replicate the functionality. Here is a [minimal example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ace_McIntosh/k8L43y3e/2/embedded/result/) to prove that this is the bit that you're looking for.

Comment: Oh well, thank you. :)